# How can I create a table in Excel from a spreadsheet that contains data that is grouped in rows

Tags: excel, datatable

I have a thousands of rows of [image: spreadsheet that contains companies addresses and contact information]here data in a spreadsheet (excel 1 image) that I need to create a table with the data populated across the headers below.

[image: Table headers]

Comment: You can use PowerQuery

Comment: -    Create a row using formula for the first entry in the first row after last column. 
-    Ensure that you get all columns that you need in one row.
-    Select cells in this row with output along with blank rows till the next record. 
-    Copy these cells
-    Drag Down below or Select Till Last and Paste.
-    Copy All and Paste as Values
-    Sort

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a VBA or spend time with other custom queries, you can do something like this (not, need to create helper column):

Create a helper column that does a count if:

[image]

Using this formula:

```
=IF(B2="Facility ID:", COUNTIFS($B$1:B2,"Facility ID:"),"")
```

[image]

Then structure your data table like this:

[image]

And you can use this formula (starting in cell I7):

```
=INDEX($A:$E,MATCH($H7,$A:$A,0)+I$4,I$5)
```

[image]

Then all you need to do is drag down the rows and increment the counts and it should work provided that the spacings always stay the same and the locations of the fields also stay the same

Answer (score 0):

*This solution requires a version of Excel that supports XLOOKUP and Dynamic Arrays.*

I would add two columns. One to count records and one to count the line number of the record like so.

[image: Sample data]

E2 is `=IF(A2="Facility ID:",MAX(E1:$E$1)+1,E1)` and F2 is `=IF(E2=E1,F1+1,1)`.  Those formulas are dragged all the way down with the exception of the last row.  That is a 6 manually entered because the typical 4th and 5th line are missing from that record.

Then sheet2 looks like this.

[image: Sample output]

A2 counts the number of total rows of data in sheet1. `=COUNT(Sheet1!E:E)`

Rows 3 and 4 show the positions of each field within the record.

A6 starts a list from 1 to number of records. `=SEQUENCE(MAX(OFFSET(Sheet1!E2,0,0,B1)))`  This uses the dynamic array functionality to spill into multiple cells.

The formula in B6 spills into multiple cells as well.

```
=XLOOKUP($A6#&B$3,OFFSET(Sheet1!$E$2,0,0,$B$1)&OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$2,0,0,$B$1),OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,B$4,$B$1),"")
```

I used `OFFSET` in the formulas so they can update if additional data is entered.

Finally, copy the formula in B6 to the other columns.